# check to see if cell contains #na

Tags: vba

Im trying to use the below to see if a cell contains #na then clear the contents. But keep getting an error

```
For k = 17 To i


 If WorksheetFunction.IsNA.sh.Range("G" & k) Then
        sh.Range("D:" & k).Clear
        
        
        
        
       
    End If
    
Next k
```

Comment: `WorksheetFunction.IsNA(sh.Range("G" & k))`

Comment: What error are you getting? @Nathan_Sav's comment is likely correct.

Comment: application or object defined error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also do that faster without a loop:

```
sh.range("G17:G" &  i).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlerrors).Clear
```

If the range contains formulas rather than constants, just replace
`xlCellTypeConstants` by `xlCellTypeFormulas`

However you won't be able to target specific errors.

Comment: it works but for some reason it gives a run time error

Comment: okay I see why. for all the cells that dont have NA it will give an error

Comment: @tech tutors No need to loop ! Do it on the whole range at once. Much faster

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
For k = 17 To i
    If WorksheetFunction.IsNA(sh.Range("G" & k).Value) Then
        sh.Range("D" & k).Clear
    End If
Next k
```